# Know the user who increase your reputation or who gave you an up vote

Tags: feature-request

I'm still new here and not yet familiar with many of the features of the forum.

I would like to know if there is a way to determine or know the user who increased your reputation or who gave you an up vote.

Back then we have a Philippine version of Stackoverflow.com for Filipino programmers and we had there a feature that displays the list and history of users who gave you an up vote.

Do we have it here also?

Answer (score 8):

No, on Stack Exchange sites like this one there is no simple way for ordinary users to see who has voted on a post.

While it would sometimes be fun to know who gave you an up/down vote, anonymized voting is important as it allows people to vote based on the post itself without worrying about maintaining friendships or not offending anyone.

Comment: I see.  That's very clear now.  Thanks!